# How to deal with unknown characters in Kotlin?

Tags: android, bluetooth, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am currently writing an Android app in Kotlin (targetting API 25+) that will connect to a custom BLE peripheral device. The custom BLE device is verified working using Lightblue Explorer (*iOS*) and nRF Connect (*iOS & Android*) to log and verify the datastream. The device name appears correctly within both the Lightblue and nRF applications.

The issue is that the device name has unknown characters appended to it when scanning within my Kotlin application, see below:

Expected: `ABC_DEF`

Actual: `ABC_DEF??`

I get the device name within the following function:

```
override fun onScanResult(callbackType: Int, result: ScanResult?) {
    val name = result!!.scanRecord.deviceName
    System.out.print("onScanResult: $name")
    attemptConnect(result!!)
}
```

My application is attempting to connect to a specific device name, thus, the connection fails due to the unknown characters.

Currently, `name.chunked(7)[0]` provides me with the *expected* name, though this solution seems hacky and I'm sure will break as soon as I change the device name.

So, my question is two-fold:

> 1. How best should I deal with these unknown characters in a way that will allow code to be reusable with a different device name?
> 2. What could be the cause of this issue?

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: Have you analyzed the bytes of the device name? If you know what chars are actually appended, you may find the reason for it.

Comment: @DenisLoh Not as of yet, that's a lower priority whilst I have this workaround as the code doesn't necessarily need to be reusable at this point in time. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: If you are only using `result!!` when why is the type provided to it a `Result?`?